# Uploaded files gets deleted automatically?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, file-upload

I have written a servlet to upload a file using a form. Before I used an absolute path like:
`String path = "C:\\Folder\\SubFolder\\";` and used this path to save the files I uploaded and it worked fine. I changed the path of the upload to: `String path = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"\\Folder\\SubFolder\\";` and now I see that the files would be automatically deleted after a while.

My question is, is it considered a temporary file and gets deleted after a while or is it some other reason? Here is my code:

```
uploadFile file = new uploadFile();// upload the file!
boolean checker = false;
String uploadPath = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("")+"\\uploads\\riparazione\\"; 
checker =  file.doImport(idRiparazione, request, response, sourceFile, uploadPath);
```

The `doImport` function is below:

```
public boolean doImport(String name, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FileItem item, String uploadPath) {
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    factory.setSizeThreshold(THRESHOLD_SIZE);
    factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);
    upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

    // creates the directory if it does not exist
    File uploaddir = new File(uploadPath);
    if ( !uploaddir.exists())
        uploaddir.mkdirs();

    String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
    fileName = name + "-" + fileName;
    String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;

    try {
        // saves the file on disk
        File storeFile = new File(filePath);
        if ( !storeFile.exists())
            item.write(storeFile);
        else return false;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

I'm using xampp for Apache tomcat 7.0, eclipse and OS is windows 7.